# image does not display on the header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, frontend

The logo (image link is correct) does not display on the header. Do you have any idea why? Is it some kind of bootstrap class not allowing it?

This is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Gianpa\Desktop\banco di prova coding\sito prova\css\bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Gianpa\Desktop\banco di prova coding\sito prova\css\banco prova css.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a id="logoheader" class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    </div>

      <!-- general menu for all devices except xs ones --> 
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right visible-lg visible-md visible-sm">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Servizi</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contattaci</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Referenze</a></li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Menu on the right -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul id="navlist" class="nav navbar-nav hidden visible-xs">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Servizi</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contattaci</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Referenze</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</header>
</body>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="display-4">Hello, world!</h1>
  <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
  <p class="lead">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

The CSS file:

```
body {background-color: #d4f9f7;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;}

#logoheader {
background: url('C:\Users\Gianpa\Desktop\banco di prova coding\sito prova\images\logo.jpg');
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
margin: 20px 20px 10px 0;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Gianpa\Desktop\banco di prova coding\sito prova\css\bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Gianpa\Desktop\banco di prova coding\sito prova\css\banco prova css.css">
```

You don't need to specify the whole directory. Just take your path as your folder. and

Use '/' instead of '\'

Comment: thanks, but it's still not working. it's like it does not even recognize there is an image

Comment: Have you tried chaning on this `background: url('C:\Users\Gianpa\Desktop\banco di prova coding\sito prova\images\logo.jpg');` or Instead of  using spaces try underscores

Answer (score 0):

You need to use relative paths, so instead of writing: *C:\Users\Gianpa\Desktop\banco di prova coding\sito prova\css\bootstrap.min.css"*,
you can just use
**/sito prova/css/bootstrap.min.css"** provided *banco di prova coding* is the root directory you're working from.

The logo is not appearing because of this path problem. In your CSS, try changing
`url('C:\Users\Gianpa\Desktop\banco di prova coding\sito prova\images\logo.jpg');`
to
`url('/sito prova/images/logo.jpg');`

You can learn more about relative and absolute paths here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp